# How to compile this project into ARM architecture for iOS

Tags: c++, ios, cmake, cross-compiling

I am using this project as a library to develop iOS programs: http://github.com/chili-epfl/chilitags

After compiling this project by CMake, the architecture of this file is x86.

However, iPhone requires ARM architecture and this library cannot be run in real devices.

I know I need to modify this project's CMake files into cross-compiling but I have no idea how to do it. I know I should use CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE and something like that but there is no good tutorial when I search.

So, how to cross compile this project into ARM architecture? Please be specific. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `I know I should use CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE and something like that but there is no good tutorial when I search.` - You need to download toolchain file for your platform, and pass `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=<path-to-toolchain-file>` option to `cmake`. As for obtaining a toolchain file itself, use google (or other search engine).

Comment: Yes I've tried that, but new errors occurs. `CMake Error at /Users/Icarus/Downloads/polly-master/utilities/polly_fatal_error.cmake:10 (message):
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /Users/Icarus/Downloads/polly-master/utilities/polly_ios_development_team.cmake:15 (polly_fatal_error)
  /Users/Icarus/Downloads/polly-master/ios-11-0.cmake:40 (include)
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.9.5/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:94 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:23 (project)` I really don't know what to do...

Comment: The error message is above call stack you show. This is actual line produces the error is [utilities/polly_ios_development_team.cmake:15](https://github.com/ruslo/polly/blob/master/utilities/polly_ios_development_team.cmake#L15). Note on its "see details" appendix.